# How do I close all issues at the same time on GitHub?

Tags: github

Is it possible to **close all issues at the same time** on GitHub

or I can only manually close them one by one?

I don't want to remove my repository and create another (because I want to keep my commits),

any possible way?

Comment: You could write a script and do it via the api. Or you can disable Issues.

Answer (score 0):

Using [GitHub CLI (gh)](https://cli.github.com/) and [jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/):

```bash
GITHUB_REPO="user_name/repo_name"
while true; do
  for n in $(gh api -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" /repos/"$GITHUB_REPO"/issues\?state=open | jq '.[] | select(.pull_request == null) | .number')
    do echo '{"state":"closed"}' | gh api -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" --method PATCH  /repos/"GITHUB_REPO"/issues/"$n" --input - | jq '.title'
  done
done
```

Make sure to update `GITHUB_REPO` value according to your user/organization name and repo name.

This will run an infinite loop that will keep fetching open issues and closing them. **There is no exit condition in the loop, so make sure to monitor the issues and exit the command using `^C`.**

APIs used:

- [List repository issues](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/issues/issues?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-repository-issues)
- [Update an issue](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/issues/issues?apiVersion=2022-11-28#update-an-issue)